# Turn off buzz when plugging in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios

I keep my iPhone on silent pretty much all the time. When I plug it in to a charger, it goes "buzz-buzz". My iPad doesn't do this. Both behaviors are the same with iOS 6 and 7.

How do I make my phone not do that?

I have checked the activity-specific sound settings (like Lock Sounds [off], etc). The main suspicious ones are Vibrate on ring and vibrate on silent. I would still like to have it buzz (vibrate) upon receiving texts, calls, and calendar alerts.

Comment: I would love to be able to do this, because if I forget and leave my iPhone plugged into the Mac at night, the Mac comes up to a semi-sleep several times in the night, USB power comes on and BRRRRT BRRRRT - the phone wakes me up. Super stupid that such a "feature" can't be disabled.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Update to iOS 9.
2. Go to Settings, Sounds, Vibrate on Silent and deactivate it.

Comment: Wish I could upvote more.

Comment: Nice. In iOS 16 this option is now called *Play Haptics in Silent Mode*. Too bad it is all or nothing.

Answer (score 10):

Plug in your head phones into the phone, turn off silent mode and turn your headphones volume down.

You may also want to turn off vibrations in sounds then charge your phone! It will make no vibrations and if you put it back on mute, your phone won't vibrate as well :)

Comment: Clever, if inconvenient.

Comment: Why turning off silent mode?

Comment: I couldn't get this to work, and other comments on this page suggest that this is impossible.  Please elaborate on instructions if this really does work.

Comment: This works. I'm running iOS 8.4 on an iPhone 5 - I turned my headphone volume down to mute in case that matters. I also have all settings in Sounds to silent. To deal with the inconvenience of the cord I used an old old auxiliary cable, cut the cord, and then plugged that in.

Comment: What a true apple workaround.

Answer (score 9):

There is no way to natively disable this other than turning off vibrations completely. Only your iPhone does this because the iPad (and the iPod touch) don't have vibrate motors.

If you jailbreak, there is a tweak called [PowerSoundDisabler](http://cydia.saurik.com/package/me.k3a.powersounddisabler). It's a simple tweak to disable sound and vibration when respringing or plugging in via USB.

Comment: Even if you turn off vibrations completely there will be vibration when you plug your phone to a charger.

Comment: @bessarabov I can confirm that. It is slightly annoying I you find yourself in school library, where every sound matters.

Comment: the tweak works on IOS6

Answer (score 0):

To do this you will have to Jailbreak your phone.

Comment: Might you be able to expand on this with a link to the mod that works with iOS 7 (or at least iOS 6) in case someone wants to try this?

Comment: Might I also point out that I already addressed that in my post, with a link to a specific tweak...